# F# Lazy Evaluation vs Non-Lazy

Tags: f#, lazy-evaluation

I'm just beginning F# so please be kind if this is basic.

I've read that a function marked lazy is evaluated only once and then cached. For example:

```
let lazyFunc = lazy (1 + 1)
let theValue = Lazy.force lazyFunc
```

Compared to this version which would actually run each time it's called:

```
let eagerFunc = (1 + 1)
let theValue = eagerFunc
```

Based on that, should **all** functions be made lazy? When would you not want to? This is coming from material in the book *"Beginning F#"*.

Comment: What version of F# is this? I have a sequence that is acting lazily, but was not overtly created that way. I'm trying to force it to complete.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, it may be helpful to note that none of the things you have defined is a function - `eagerFunc` and `theValue` are values of type `int` and `lazyFunc` is a value of type `Lazy<int>`.  Given

```
let lazyTwo = lazy (1 + 1)
```

and

```
let eagerTwo = 1 + 1
```

the expression `1 + 1` will **not** be evaluated more than once no matter how many times you use `eagerTwo`.  The difference is that `1 + 1` will be evaluated *exactly* once when *defining* `eagerTwo`, but will be evaluated *at most* once when `lazyTwo` is *used* (it will be evaluated the first time that the `Value` property is accessed, and then cached so that further uses of `Value` do not need to recalculated it).  If `lazyTwo`'s `Value` is never accessed, then its body `1 + 1` will *never* be evaluated.

Typically, you won't see much benefit to using lazy values in a strict language like F#.  They add a small amount of overhead since accessing the `Value` property requires checking whether the value has already been calculated.  They might save you a bit of calculation if you have something like `let lazyValue = lazy someVeryExpensiveCalculationThatMightNotBeNeeded()`, since the expensive calculation will only take place if the value is actually used.  They can also make some algorithms terminate which otherwise would not, but this is not a major issue in F#.  For instance:

```
// throws an exception if x = 0.0
let eagerDivision x =
    let oneOverX = 1.0 / x
    if x = 0.0 then
        printfn "Tried to divide by zero" // too late, this line is never reached
    else
        printfn "One over x is: %f" oneOverX

// succeeds even if x = 0.0, since the quotient is lazily evaluated
let lazyDivision x =
    let oneOverX = lazy (1.0 / x)
    if x = 0.0 then
        printfn "Tried to divide by zero"
    else
        printfn "One over x is: %f" oneOverX.Value
```

Comment: Doesn't using `()` imply that it's a function? Good points in any case. You're right my examples are super trivial.

Comment: @Yuck - parentheses mean different things in different contexts.  When you use them like `(1 + 1)` then they are merely serving to indicate grouping and precedence.  If you had defined `let eagerFunc() = ...` then the parentheses indicate that `eagerFunc` is a function, but note that this is different from what you wrote.

Answer (score 7):

If function executions have side-effects and it is important to see the side-effects each time the function is called (say it wraps an I/O function) you would not want it to be lazy.

There are also functions that are so trivial that executing them each time is faster than caching the value--

Answer (score 6):

`let eagerFunc = (1 + 1)` is a let binding, and will only execute once. `let eagerFunc() = (1 + 1)` is a function accepting `unit` (nothing) and returning an `int`. It will execute each time it's called. In a sense, every function is lazy, that is, it only executes when called. However, the `lazy` keyword (and `System.Lazy`, which it returns) will execute the expression/function given to it at most once. Subsequent calls to the `Value` property will return the cached result. This is useful when computation of the value is expensive.

Many functions will not be suitable for use with `lazy` because they are either non-deterministic (may return a different result with each invocation) or parameterized. Of course, it's possible to use a fully-applied (a value is supplied for each parameter) version of such functions, but generally the variability is desired.