# Lazy evaluation within F# closures

Tags: f#, closures, lazy-evaluation

This is a F# closure. The code sample is inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924/f-closure)

```
let isPasswordBetter (newPassword:string) (currPassword:string) =

    let isLongEnough = newPassword.Length > 1

    let newIsLongerThanCurrent = 
        (newPassword.Length > currPassword.Length)

    if isLongEnough then
        if newIsLongerThanCurrent then
            true
        else
            false
    else
        false

let result1 = isPasswordBetter "a" "hello"
let result2 = isPasswordBetter "hellothere" "hello"
let result3 = isPasswordBetter "aaa" "hello"
```

Let's assume for a minute that `newIsLongerThanCurrent` is very computationally expensive.

If I understand correctly [F# is lazy by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683830/f-lazy-evaluation-vs-non-lazy), that means that `newIsLongerThanCurrent` will be always evaluated before getting to the `if than` even if its evaluation may not be necessary. Hence, I should make it [lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233247.aspx) explicitly.

Is my understanding correct? I'd rather avoid clutter code, if `lazy` is not necessary to defer the computation of `newIsLongerThanCurrent`

Comment: Thank you all for the help and yes, F# is **NOT** lazy by default..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# is `not` lazy by default.
The laziest 'lazy' approach is converting `newIsLongerThanCurrent` to the function:

```
let newIsLongerThanCurrent() = 
    (newPassword.Length > currPassword.Length)
```

and applying it in `if`-clause:

```
if isLongEnough then
    if newIsLongerThanCurrent() then
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Eugene is correct in saying that F# is *not* lazy by default. And in this case, turning `newIsLongerThanCurrent` into a function is the best approach.

In general, F# provides one more way of adding laziness which is done using the `lazy` keyword. This is useful if you need to access the value multiple times (because it caches the result, while running a function multiple times would run the computation repeatedly).

```
let newIsLongerThanCurrent = 
    lazy (newPassword.Length > currPassword.Length)

if isLongEnough then
    if newIsLongerThanCurrent.Value then                // Computation evaluated here
        let x = newIsLongerThanCurrent.Value || other   // ..the result is reused here
        (...)
```